# infinite loop in C#

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

This simple program take an input of integers and print them , but stop printing if it sees 60

```
        string input = string.Empty;
        int intValue = 0;
        int[] numbers = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(input, out intValue))
                numbers[i] = intValue;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            while (numbers[i] != 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(intValue);
            }
        }
```

the program go on an infinite loop after the 4th input 
like that
    Input:
    1
    2
    3
    4
    4
    4
    4
    4
    4 ........ and so on

and i don't know the reason .... ^_^

Comment: What do you think `while (numbers[i] != 60)` does?

Comment: It is because of your while loop. Why are you doing this  - while (numbers[i] != 60) ? Edited: Have you tried debugging your code before posting here?

Comment: Your example output doesn't make sense.  This code should repeatedly output 0 (since intValue is never assigned a different value) and it will never make it to i=2, 3, or 4.  Your `while` loop should be an `if` with a `break;` inside

Comment: Come on guys don't be so rude, we were newbies once too

Comment: i thought it works like if ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (numbers[i] != 60)
{
    Console.WriteLine(intValue);
}
```

should be:

```
if (numbers[i] != 60)
{
    Console.WriteLine(intValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string input = string.Empty;

```
    int intValue = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(input, out intValue))
            numbers[i] = intValue;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        /*while (numbers[i] != 60)*/
        if (numbers[i] != 60)  // it should be if condition, while statement made it infinite
        {
            Console.WriteLine(intValue);
        }
    }
```